# The best way to pull an Id from a SOQL collection by using the name of the record in Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, collection

I am looking to set a lookup field of a new object record created in Apex by referencing a collection from a SOQL query.

An example would be:

```
List<SObject> soqlQuery = [SELECT Id, Name FROM SObject]

Sobject2 newSOj = new Sobject2();
newSOj.lookup1 = (ID from soqlQuery where name equals 'ABC'
```

The reason for doing this is that I am building the logic in Sandbox and need it to translate to production. I know the record Id's in Sandbox but realize this will not translate to Production when the code is deployed.

Might there be a better way of approaching this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help and please let me know if you need me to clarify anything!

Comment: Might there be a better way? Definitely yes. This solution is fragile and ripe for causing you problems in the long run. What's the business use case you're solving for here where you want to rely on a record's given name?

Comment: I started writing an answer, but Mark's comment made me reconsider. Generally speaking, the straight answer to what you're asking would be to create a Map (a type of collection). Whether or not that's the right approach (or part of the right approach) depends on the details. Right now, I think this is an X-Y problem (you're asking about your attempted solution, rather than the problem you're trying to solve).

Comment: @MarkPond I have an object called a Payment Plan and there is a junction object called Payment Plan Codes which relates the Payment Plan with another object called Payment Codes.

I have created a number of Payment Code records, which have name identifiers (eg. Hardware 1, Service 2).

Depending on the values stored on the Payment Plan I want to be able to relate the correct Payment Code records to the Payment Plan Code JO.

e.g If Hardware products are included in the Payment Plan then the Payment Plan Code JO will have the related 'Hardware 1' Payment Code